# Select all the duplicate records other than minimun

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in MySQL wiht name as below

[image]

I have two things to process

1- Deactivate all the books which are not in use

```
isActive = 1 - Active
isActive = 0  - Inactive

is_inuse = 1 - in use
is_inuse = 0 - not in use
I have the query as such
```

. . .

```
update books 
set is_active=0 
where book_name in (select (book_name) 
                    from books  
                    group by book_name 
                    having count(1) >1
                   ) and 
      is_inuse != 1;
```

2 -Rename all the duplicate books except the one with minimum book id, append book_id before name of the book.
struggling to make the query for this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get the list of the duplicate book name using the below SQL

```
select t1.book_id, t1.book_name, concat(t1.book_id, t1.book_name) as new_name 
from table1 t1,
(
select book_name, min(book_id) as book_id from table1
group by book_name
) t2
where t1.book_name = t2.book_name
and t1.book_id != t2.book_id
```

Comment: Thank you, I spent around 2 days to make this query ... hats off